# Visual Studios PowerShell Convert PDF to TIF folder path requires double \\

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2019

when converting my `.pdf` to a `.tif` the only way i can get the output in the correct folder is by putting double `\\` in manually is there a way i can have these already put into my folder that is selected

Convert `.pdf` to `.tif` code below *this isn't mine just been adapted to suit me

```
#Path to your Ghostscript EXE

$tool = "C:\\Program Files\\gs\\gs9.52\\bin\\gswin64c.exe"

#Directory containing the PDF files that will be converted
$inputDir = $textbox2.Text

#Output path where the TIF files will be saved
$outputDir = $textbox3.Text

$pdfs = get-childitem $inputDir -recurse | where {$_.Extension -match "pdf"}

foreach($pdf in $pdfs)
{
    $tif = $outputDir + $pdf.BaseName + ".tif"
    if(test-path $tif)
    {
       $tif
    }
    else        
    {   
        'Processing ' + $pdf.Name        
        $param = "-sOutputFile=$tif"
        & $tool -q -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=tiff24nc $param -r300 $pdf.FullName -c quit 
    }

}
}
```

[image]

as you can see the Tif Folder has the path layout i need

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking for... if it's how to take a normal path and double up the back-slashes, this would work:  ("C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.52\bin\gswin64c.exe").Replace('\', '\\')

Comment: that's what i am asking but the only problem is the user must select the path first

Comment: so then, if 'Tif Folder' is a button to a folderdiaglogbox, then you'd run the replace() on the path returned from the that part of your gui...

Comment: @thepip3r that sounds like what i need any chance you could show me how that would look please

Comment: Are you authoring this GUI you provided screen shots for or is this an application that already exists?

Comment: this is mine i have created it. this is my first time ever doing this

Comment: If 'Tif Folder' is a button to that pops up a OpenFileDialogue box, then apply the replace on that output.  If you're asking how to use a OpenFileDialogue box:  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/hey-scripting-guy-can-i-open-a-file-dialog-box-with-windows-powershell/.  If you're just asking how to take a path from that text field and convert it to double back-slash, you don't need to have the user add it in that way, you can have them provide the actual path and then when they click whatever button executes the conversion process, you perform the replace() at runtime.

Comment: thank you for your help